# Twitter "status update" url not working on iOS

Tags: ios, twitter

I've added a "tweet this" link to a site. It uses the url to update your Twitter status (if you're signed in). Basic version is as follows:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/home/?status=TEST STATUS">Twitter</a>
```

You can see it in action here - http://jsfiddle.net/CXzf9/1/ - right click the link to open in a new window (need to be logged in to Twitter first).

Works fine except on iOS devices. Then it gives you an error saying "Sorry that page doesn't exist". You can also see this using Safari when set to the iPad user agent. It redirects from

```
http://twitter.com/home/?status=TEST STATUS
```

to

```
https://mobile.twitter.com/home/?status=TEST STATUS
```

But it's not that causing the problem, as if you visit that link in Safari (with the usual user agent) you get the mobile version, but it's still allowing you to update your status.

Is this some iOS restriction?

UPDATE - VISUAL EXPLANATION:

This is visiting mobile link in Safari:

[image]

This is same link with user agent set to iPad:

[image]

Comment: How are you using this in your iOS app? i bet you are not url encoding :-)

Comment: It's actually in a Magento store, and yes the url is encoded - <?php echo urlencode($productUrl); ?>. Works fine except for iOS.

Comment: Ok, you are confusing me. Can you post the iOS code, where you are trying to get the status update?

Comment: There's no iOS code. It's just a standard link, as per the jsfiddle link I posted above. If you try visit that link on your browser, it will update your twitter status, if you try from an iPad, it throws an error.

Comment: Ok, now I got it. It's obviously the user agent doing this. You can confirm this by changing your Firefox user agent to match the iPad mobile Safari user agent (there is an extension that does this) and verify. You should use their API in that case, as I cannot think of an alternate solution

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, seems it works if you use the following url:

```
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=
```

So original code would be:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=TEST STATUS">Twitter</a>
```

Must be some iOS restriction on updating a status for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

after trying on my iPad, I got undefined as the title and text saying "something went wrong". if this is what you are receiving, then it's because twitter does not have a mobile version of this page. Hence "mobile.twitter.com". I would recommend using the twitter api ([here](https://dev.twitter.com/)) to update a uses status.

Comment: But as I said above, if you visit the mobile version of the link in Safari for example, it works fine, but if user agent is set to iPad it doesn't work. Very confusing.

Answer (score -1):

Official Twitter documentation about creating post links:

https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button/web-intent

> ## Web Intent URL
>
> https://twitter.com/intent/tweet
>
> **Query parameters**
>
> - text (*optional*)
>
> Pre-populated UTF-8 and URL-encoded
>   Tweet text. The passed text will appear pre-selected for a Twitter
>   user to delete or edit before posting.
>
> The length of your passed Tweet text should not exceed 140 characters
>   when combined with any passed hashtags, via, or url parameters. Passed
>   Tweet text which causes the Tweet to exceed 140 characters in length
>   will require additional editing by a Twitter user before he or she can
>   successfully post.
>
> Example Value: Hello%20World
>
> - url (*optional*)
>
> A fully-qualified URL with a HTTP or HTTPS scheme,
>   URL-encoded. The provided URL will be shortened with Twitter’s t.co to
>   the number of characters specified by short_url_length.
>
> Example Value: http:%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F
>
> - hashtags (*optional*)
>
> Allow easy discovery of Tweets by topic by including
>   a comma-separated list of hashtag values without the preceding #
>   character.
>
> Example Value: nature,sunset
>
> - via (*optional*)
>
> A Twitter username to associate with the Tweet, such as
>   your site’s Twitter account. The provided username will be appended to
>   the end of the Tweet with the text “via @username”.
>
> A logged-out Twitter user will be encouraged to sign-in or join
>   Twitter to engage with the via account’s Tweets. The account may be
>   suggested as an account to follow after the user posts a Tweet
>
> Example Value: twitterdev
>
> - related (*optional*)
>
> Suggest additional Twitter usernames related to the
>   Tweet as comma-separated values. Twitter may suggest these accounts to
>   follow after the user posts his or her Tweet.
>
> You may provide a brief description of how the account relates to the
>   Tweet with a URL-encoded comma and text after the username.
>
> Example Value:
>   twitter%3ATwitter%20News,twitterapi%3ATwitter%20API%20News
>
> - in-reply-to (*optional*)
>
> The Tweet ID of a parent Tweet in a conversation,
>   such as the initial Tweet from your site or author account.
>
> Example Value: 525001166233403393

Example post link: https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Hello%20World&via=twitterdev

Comment: @CalebKleveter Ok, I've expanded my answer. Thank you for your advice